# Computer freezing on BIOS screen

Tags: bios, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer hangs at BIOS screen. Cannot enter setup](https://superuser.com/questions/224557/computer-hangs-at-bios-screen-cannot-enter-setup)

Ive had my computer for a few years now and I just started coming across this problem.

Some days, I'll boot my computer and it will freeze on the BIOS screen (before windows even load!)

What can I do?